# Unable to transfer images and videos over NFC and wifi on sony a6000

Tags: troubleshooting, wifi

I'm not able to transfer images and videos from the Sony α6000 to my smartphone via NFC or wifi. It's just says 'sending cancelled' on the camera and 'unable to connect' on the smartphone. Please advise. I have used the above to successfully transfer images before.

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the world of "innovation" and "cutting edge" technology where beta-level products are released before being adequately tested in a wide number of scenarios which the users may find themselves in, all so the company releasing them can toot their own horn about how far ahead of everyone else they are!

Comment: [Sony...](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99367/75526) The folks who brought us Betamax, MiniDisc, ATRAC, and Memory Stick... and [installed malware on its customers' computers](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2194292/network-security/sony-bmg-rootkit-scandal--5-years-later.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that NFC isn't always working to well for me either (Sony A77II).

Try opening the app and manually configuring the wifi connection.
After this opening the app using NFC or just opening the app manually will give an instant working connection regardless of any planet alignments.